# How to do an OR condition on result, when using Spring MockMVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit, mockito, mockmvc

Currently I have below -

```
.andExpect(org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.message",
                            org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo("storeCode cannot be blank text; storeCode cannot be null")));
```

**How can i add an `OR` condition to the above,** something like below (ofcourse, below does not work)

```
.andExpect(org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.message",
                            org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo("storeCode cannot be blank text; storeCode cannot be null").OR.equalTo("storeCode cannot be null; storeCode cannot be blank text")));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`either`](https://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.2/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#either-org.hamcrest.Matcher-), [`anyOf`](https://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.2/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#anyOf-org.hamcrest.Matcher...-), or [`oneOf`](https://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.2/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#oneOf-T...-) matchers.

`either`:

```
.andExpect(
    MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath(
        "$.message",
        Matchers.either(Matchers.equalTo("storeCode cannot be blank text; storeCode cannot be null"))
        .or(Matchers.equalTo("storeCode cannot be null; storeCode cannot be blank text"))));
```

`anyOf`:

```
.andExpect(
    MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath(
        "$.message",
        Matchers.anyOf(
            Matchers.equalTo("storeCode cannot be blank text; storeCode cannot be null"),
            Matchers.equalTo("storeCode cannot be null; storeCode cannot be blank text"))));
```

`oneOf`:

```
.andExpect(
    MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath(
        "$.message",
        Matchers.oneOf(
            "storeCode cannot be blank text; storeCode cannot be null",
            "storeCode cannot be null; storeCode cannot be blank text")));
```

Or use a regular expression with [`matchesPattern`](https://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.2/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#matchesPattern-java.lang.String-):

```
.andExpect(
    MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath(
        "$.message",
        Matchers.matchesPattern(
            "storeCode cannot be blank text; storeCode cannot be null|storeCode cannot be null; storeCode cannot be blank text"))));
```